# NextJS 11 rendering dynamic content from getServerSideProps depending on domain?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, multi-tenant

I have a multitenancy website that has multiple domains with the same tld.

For example

- `stagingus.sitename.net`
- `staginguk.sitename.net`
- `dev.sitename.co.uk`
- `dev.sitename.com`
- `dev.sitename.co.uk`
- `sitename.com`
- `sitename.co.uk`
- `site-name.com`
- `site-name.co.uk`

I initially was going to go down the route of Internationalization, using `i18n` setting in `next.config.js` but was thwarted by the fact that you cannot have multiple domains with the same locale, for example

```
i18n: {
  locales: ['en-GB', 'en-US'],
  defaultLocale: 'en-GB',
  localeDetection: false,
  domains: [
    {
      domain: 'sitename.co.uk',
      defaultLocale: 'en-GB',
    },
    {
      domain: 'sitename.com',
      defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    },
    {
      domain: 'dev.sitename.com',
      defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    },
  ],
},
```

throws the following error

```
Both dev.sitename.com and sitename.com configured the defaultLocale en-US but only one can. Change one item's default locale to continue
Error: Invalid i18n.domains values:
{"domain":"sitename.com","defaultLocale":"en-US"}
{"domain":"dev.sitename.com","defaultLocale":"en-US"}

domains value must follow format { domain: 'example.fr', defaultLocale: 'fr', locales: ['fr'] }.
```

I cannot rely on the TLD either, as `stagingus.sitename.net` and `staginguk.sitename.net` both end in `.net` but would offer different content.

So I am not sure if it's just going to be a case of checking if the current host is a UK or US domain with something like this is in a `getServerSideProps` function?

```
const isUS = ctx.req.headers.host.match(someUsDomainRegex));
```

Unless there is some other method I am unaware of?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the way to conditionally execute code based on the subdomain of the current domain, you could write your code something like this.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  if (ctx.req.headers.host?.startsWith?.("dev")) {
    return; // ... data for development
  }
  // ...
}
```

Of course if you know the sub-domain structure you can always implement a helper function to make this process less tedious and the code reusable so you can implement it in multiple pages:

```
export async function getHostType(host: string) {
  const separated = host.split(".");

  if (host?.startsWith?.("dev")) {
    return { type: "dev", country: null };
  }

  if (host?.startsWith?.("staging")) {
    const country = separated[0].replace("staging", "");
    return { type: "staging", country };
  }

  const country = separated[separated.length - 1];
  return { type: "production", country: country !== "com" ? country : null };
}
```